# What's missing from this jQuery script for simple datepicker?

Tags: jquery

I can't figure out where I've gone wrong with this.

I have the following code added to my header:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8.11/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css">
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<script>
$(function(){
    $("#tmp_input-41178").datepicker();
});
</script>
```

My input field ID is:
id="tmp_input-41178"

This is not working at all. Am I missing something?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It should be working, the issues I am seeing is you are defining JQuery UI twice

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8.11/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
```

and

```
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>
```

and the first one is called before declaring JQuery. so remove the first line and check. Also make sure that the input field is there when the page is loaded (since you named it 'tmp*' i am suspecting it is loaded sometimes later based on some actions. if that is the case, you need to call

```
$("#tmp_input-41178").datepicker();
```

after you inserted the element.

https://jsfiddle.net/Lbje85mn/ is a working version of your code.

Comment: Thanks for your help with this. I've deleted the first line as directed but it still doesn't work. 

The input field appears to load immediately but I'm guessing the problem might have something to do with it since there's no problem with the script.

Here's a link to the page > https://www.minutecarrentals.com/test-001

Thanks @Vilsad

Comment: your id is given to a div, not to the input field itself. if you must give id to the parent div, change your code to $("#tmp_input-41178 > input").datepicker();

Comment: Hey @Vilsad, thanks again. I've changed the code to $("#tmp_input-41178 > input").datepicker(); , but unfortunately it's still not working. Is there any other potential issues you see?

Comment: can you upload this to a jsfiddle ?

Comment: I can't make any changes to the HTML code though. I can only change the script. Thanks...

Comment: can you remove Jquery or lander.js ? i suspect Jquery is loaded twice (lander.js has a comment of Jquery, maybe it is loading its own version) and try ?

Comment: I can only add code to the header, or make changes to this Jquery code in the jsfiddle. I unfortunately can't make changes to anything else.

I've tried removing:

1. https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js
2. https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js

And running the script but same results.

Comment: ok, please change your code like below $.noConflict(); $("#tmp_input-41178 > input").datepicker();

Comment: OK, changed code to: 

$(function(){
    $.noConflict(); $("#tmp_input-41178 > input").datepicker();
});
</script>

Still not working :(

Comment: I can see  it is working on your link, try clicking the pickup date field and calendar is displayed

Comment: Oh wow! You are correct! Had to do a hard refresh! So the problem was a conflict. Thank you very much! How can I buy you a drink??

Comment: glad its working, help others in need and consider the drink is done :) please  mark this as answer so others can find easily

Comment: My original problem was fixed with the $.noConflict(); but I now realize that it's preventing my pop-up from working. Is there any other workaround? Thanks...

Comment: there is no workaround, you will have to contact the team who can edit the html file to get  duplicate JQuery script removed.